# NFS mount works, but autofs fails with remote IO error

Tags: automount, 20.10, nfs

The NFS server is AIX v7.2 and the client is Ubuntu Server 20.10. Here is the problem.

Results of `showmount -e tsm2.montanavendor.com` :

```
Export list for tsm2.montanavendor.com:
/export/nim/lpp_source/720303_1913                devsap01_bkup.montanavendor.com
/export/nim/spot/720303_1913/720303_1913_spot/usr devsap01_bkup.montanavendor.com
/export/nim/scripts/devsap01_bkup.script          devsap01_bkup.montanavendor.com
/nim                                              172.23.4.18,172.23.4.27,172.23.4.79,192.168.0.202
/export/nim/spot/720400_1937/720400_1937_spot/usr prdsap01_bkup.montanavendor.com
/export/nim/lpp_source/720400_1937                prdsap01_bkup.montanavendor.com
/adminBkup                                        172.23.4.18,172.23.4.27,unificntl_bkup.montanavendor.com
/tmp1                                             172.23.4.27,172.23.4.18,unificntl_bkup.montanavendor.com
```

`sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 tsm2.montanavendor.com:/tmp1 /nfs/tmp1` works and `df` yields:

```
tsm2.montanavendor.com:/tmp1           4096   257      3840   7% /nfs/tmp1
```

After umount of `/nfs/tmp1` I tried the automounter with this:

```
$ cat /etc/auto.master
/nfs    /etc/auto.nfs
/mnt    /etc/auto.mnt
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/auto.nfs
adminBkup   -rw tsm2.montanavendor.com:/adminBkup
tmp1        -rw tsm2.montanavendor.com:/tmp1
```

then `sudo automount -f -v`

```
Starting automounter version 5.1.6, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.05
mounted indirect on /nfs with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
mounted indirect on /mnt with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
```

which yields this after an access attempt:

```
attempting to mount entry /nfs/tmp1
>> mount.nfs: Remote I/O error
mount(nfs): nfs: mount failure tsm2.montanavendor.com:/tmp1 on /nfs/tmp1
failed to mount /nfs/tmp1
```

This from another session:

```
$ ls -l /nfs/tmp1
ls: cannot access '/nfs/tmp1': No such file or directory
```

This looks like an ownership or permissions problem. I've set 777 on the server directory and re-exported. I tried deleting the `/nfs/tmp1` directory before starting automount, but it didn't work. I think I am missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

I can make this a static mount, but I prefer the automounter, which is immune to server reboots.

Comment: I solved this problem after poking at it awhile more. In Ubuntu v20 (and maybe earlier) the nfs version must be explicitly stated.

Comment: Here is what worked for me:

**For a one-off mount:**

mount -t nfs -o vers=3 172.23.4.16:/adminBkup /nfs/adminBkup

**fstab stanza:**

172.23.4.16:/adminBkup  /nfs/adminBkup nfs auto,vers=3,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0

**automount map stanza:**

adminBkup -rw,tcp,vers=3 172.23.4.16:/adminBkup